# #include in middle of code

Tags: c, header

I would like to make a conditional inclusion of a header file in my program. Is it possible and, if yes, how do I do it?

My idea is to do something like this:

```
switch(opt)
{
case 0:
    {
        #include "matrix.h"
        break;
    }
case 1:
    {
        #include "grid.h"
        break;
    }
}
```

That is how VS did it when I wrote it. Is it right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At **compile time** you can have bit control of **conditional inclusion of a header file**

```
#ifdef MAGIC
#include "matrix.h"
#else
#include "grid.h"
#endif
```

at compile time

```
gcc -D MAGIC=1 file.c
```

or

```
gcc file.c
```

But at **run-time**  **conditional inclusion of a header file** is not possible.

It means what your  pseudo code is showing is not possible.

Comment: Also, at run time it doesn't make any sense. The program would have to link itself on the fly. There are various other ways to achieve such functionality: files, DLLs etc.

Comment: yes at run time it does not make any sense. But OP has shown his interest for doing this as run time in pseudo code so i have said that.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to make a conditional inclusion of a header file in my program. Is it possible and, if yes, how do I do it?

Yes, it is possible.
C preprocessor already has directives that support *conditional compilation* Better to use

```
#ifndef expr
#include "matrix.h"
#else
#include "grid.h"
#endif
```

If `expr` has not been defined, then `matrix.h` get included otherwise if `it is defined (`#define *expr*`) then`grid.h` get included.

Comment: @JensGustedt; Yes. I mean `elif`.

Answer (score 1):

This is 2 different things. The [`#include`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html#Include-Syntax) is a preprocessor directive which is processed **at compilation time**. The `swicth` is a `C` keyword which is proccessed **at execution time**.

So, you can use the [conditional preprocessor directives](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Conditional-Syntax.html#Conditional-Syntax) in order to choose what file to include:

```
#ifdef MATRIX
#include "matrix.h"
#else
#include "grid.h"
#endif
```

Or you can also include both, because *normally*, it does not matter if you include useless header file.

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include "grid.h"


switch(opt) {
case 0:
        /* Do something with matrix functions */
        break;

case 1:
        /* Do something with grid functions */
        break;
}
```